# Shapes on a button HTML

Tags: html

I'm working on an Arduino program and I'd like to have buttons representing the LEDs on them, something like this.
[Ideal Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS0GK.jpg)

Cheers in advanced.

```
.BLANK_BUTTON{border-radius: 4px; background-color: #fff; color: #000; height: 95px; width: 350px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 25px; margin: 4px 4px; cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: I have done some research but I couldn't find anything useful. I've never programmed in HTML before. The whole code is ready and this is just a small detail that I would like to have. I could submit the button characteristics as this button already exists on my code, but it would be pointless as it is just a button and I'm a asking for a small detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam not good in css, but you can try my code,

```css
#red{display: inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background-color: red;border-radius: 50%;margin-left: 10px;}

#blue{display: inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background-color: blue;border-radius: 50%;margin-left: 10px;}

#black{display: inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background-color: black;border-radius: 50%;margin-left: 10px;}
```

```html
<button>button<span id="red"></span><span id="blue"></span><span id="black"></span></button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, you've been really helpful!